# Proof of the Three Utilities Problem with Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, graph-theory, reference-request

A very famous problem is the following:

**[The Three Utilities Problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem#:~:targetText=The%20classical%20mathematical%20puzzle%20known,%2C%20water%2C%20and%20electricity%20companies.)** *There are three houses and three utilities:
You must draw a line from each house to each utility, without the lines ever crossing. Can you connect the houses to the utilities?*

The answer is no, and this can be proved in several ways. The most popular ones perhaps are using Jordan Curve Theorem or Graph Theory.

I found this problem in a list of relatively difficult exercises of Complex Analysis, and I was wondering if anyone can help or provide a reference. I suspect that, if such a solution exists, it should be using index numbers.